# Concatenate error runtime scripting linux

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, concatenation, fedora

I was testing a menu with concatenate string, but when I execute the script, it returns this message:

```
errorsc: line 12: humans: command not found
hello
```

I checked the same sentences on terminal, and there is successful.

```
[root@localhost-localdomain username]# var='my'
[root@localhost-localdomain username]# var="${var} string"
[root@localhost-localdomain username]# echo $var
my string
```

This is the script code:

```
#!/bin/bash      
clear
OPTIONS=("first opt" "second opt" "third opt", "out")
select opt in "${OPTIONS[@]}"
do               
    if [ "$opt" = "Out" ]; then                
        echo done               
        exit           
    elif [ "$opt" = "first opt" ]; then
        clear
        var='hello '
        var= "${var} humans"
        echo $var       
    elif [ "$opt" = "second opt" ]; then
        clear
        echo "no yet"
    elif [ "$opt" = "third opt" ]; then
        clear
        echo "no yet"
    else                
           echo "error"              
    fi           
done
```

Comment: `var= "` => remove the space in there.

Comment: recommend to rewrite with case statement. These if-else statements makes me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell is very picky about spaces around `=`.

Instead of

```
        var= "${var} humans"
```

you should have :

```
        var="${var} humans"
```

**no spaces allowed** !